# Cassandra Cluster manager memory leaks

Tags: java, memory-leaks, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

We have spring boot application with spring cassandra, application crashes due to OOM for every 2 to 3 days, we need to restart the application for it to work again.

We have taken heap dump, when we ran leak suspect, we are seeing below.

> 31 instances of "io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache", loaded by
>   "org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader @ 0xe03255d0" occupy
>   30,818,712 (27.72%) bytes.
>
> 2 instances of "com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager", loaded by
>   "org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader @ 0xe03255d0" occupy
>   20,144,744 (18.12%) bytes

We are suspecting, it might be due to cluster NIO threads, please let me know if any one faced same issue.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to the basic info shared by you, the prima facie suspect in this case seems to be the inefficiency related to "io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache".

An OOM might be coming due to excessive number of threads getting spawned in PoolThreadCache(which might be using up the heap) or due to some inefficiency in which the PoolThreadCache is not able to reclaim the idle threads.

You need to debug by checking memory utilization using the **jmap** command.